# Android jetpack compose naming dimen in a separate val

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In a current project, sometimes we create properties for dimens. But is it correct to assign dimen to val when we are going to use it only once? Or maybe in this times it doesn't matter?

```
val paddingSmall = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_small)
val paddingDefault = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_default) //it is used only once
val paddingLarge = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_large)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I prefer to add a separate property even if it is used once in the project. For 2 reasons:

- As in the future, it could be re-used
- It makes it cleaner to add a property for a dimen.

Comment: That's reasonable, thanks